# StringBuilder.toString() is printed as empty string in Eclipse-console when too big?

Tags: java, eclipse, stringbuilder

The following returns nothing for me in eclipse, is this expected behaviour ?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
for(int i = 0; i < 256*256*2*6; i++) {
   sb.append("a");
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

The code returns without error and the size is well withhin memory capacity unlike in [Maximum number of characters stringbuilder can accommodate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758106/maximum-number-of-characters-stringbuilder-can-accommodate)

Solved: The problem lies in the eclipse console and enabling (Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Console -> fixed width console) will print the line normally.

Comment: No, the questions has an error, while mine just finished normally but returns nothing. Also my number isn't nearly as big and still withing int range 8+8+1+3 = 20 bit length.

Comment: its perfectly works just check out here  > https://ideone.com/nE6vEB

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem is probably your console being unable to print such a long string. If you try:

```
System.out.println(sb.toString().length());
```

instead, [it will print what you expect (786432)](http://ideone.com/oGfe3c).

Comment: I tried in eclipse, indeed it doesn't work, even though the console buffer is large enough. It seems more related to the length of the _line_, because appending `a\n` instead of `a`, will display the whole content in my case.

Comment: @Berger Do you have the *Limit Console Output* unchecked in Eclipse (Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Console)? Btw, the max for `System.out.println` is equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2,147,483,647) if I'm not mistaken, this is the max an array can hold and a String is a char[].

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen : I disabled the limit, but the huge line didn't display .

Comment: Enabling (Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Console->fixed width console) will print the line normally, and when choosing a maximum character width an error is displayed, bust be withing 80 and 1000 inclusive.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful : You're right, changing this setting immediately made the invisible line display correctly.

Comment: Additionally changing the maximum character width to anything other than 80 throws an eclipse error message at me, 'Reveal End of document' has enocuntered a problem an internal error has occured. OK || Details An Internal error has occured. [random number]